# In a Visual Studio Extension, how to respond to "Open Folder" as well as "Open Solution"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility

My Visual Studio Extension responds to the opening of a solution via `IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenSolution()`.

Visual Studio 2017 introduced ["Open Folder"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/bring-your-c-codebase-to-visual-studio-with-open-folder/) as an alternative to "Open Solution", but when you open a folder, `IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenSolution()` doesn't fire.  (Nor do any of the other events in `IVsSolutionEvents`, nor any of the events in `IVsSolutionLoadEvents`.)

How can my extension know when a Folder, as opposed to a Solution, is opened?

Comment: Are you looking for IVsSolutionEvents7::OnAfterOpenFolder?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents7?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: @SimonMourier: That looks perfect, but when I implement it and pass my implementing object to `IVsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents()`, none of the `IVsSolutionEvents7` events fires.  The object also implements `IVsSolutionEvents`, and those events do fire.  Any ideas...?

Comment: Nope, I guess this is really the only way. Some VS dll implement that interface just like that (for example Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal, class Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.StartPageToolWindowPane). You could try to implement ICustomQueryInterface temporarily just to check if it's even requesting that interface.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Aha!  Implementing ICustomQueryInterface revealed that I needed to add `[ComVisible(true)]` to my definition of `IVsSolutionEvents7`.  After that (and some more COM hoop-jumping) it's now all working - thanks!  If you'd like to create an answer from your comment, I'd be delighted to accept it and award it a bounty (when it becomes eligible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [IVsSolutionEvents7.OnAfterOpenFolder Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents7.onafteropenfolder) that has been added for Visual Studio 2017.

> Notifies listening clients that the folder has been opened.
>
> ```
> public void OnAfterOpenFolder (string folderPath);
> ```

Since this is a native COM interface, you also have to make sure the implementing class is COM visible (through the [ComVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute that you can set on the assembly, on the class, on a base class, etc.).

Comment: Wonderful - many thanks!  I have a followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432488/ on which I'd very much value your input.

Comment: @SimonMourier Do you know how to track the switch over 'Solution View' and 'Folder View' in Solution Explorer? May be there is an interface with the according methods?

Comment: @Nightwalker - you should ask another question